# How to correctly introduce an object

Tags: punctuation, colons

How do I correctly introduce the clause 'her mother's life' in this sentence? Should I use a colon, comma or something else?

> First, it is worth noting that her fear is about an object: her mother’s life

Comment: Her mother's life is an object?

Answer (score 1):

My vote is for a colon.

From [UNC's writing center](https://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/semi-colons-colons-and-dashes/): (notice how I am introducing this with a colon :P)

> **Common uses of colons**
>
> 1. To announce, introduce, or direct attention to a list, a noun or noun phrase, a quotation, or an example/explanation